# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be nul

Tags: php, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

i have this error when i try to insert a object in laravel, this is my function in controller class:

```
    public function insertDelete(Producto $item)
{
     $date = date('Y-m-d');
   $venta=new venta();

     $venta->fechaVenta=$date;
     $venta->user_id=$item->user_id;
    $venta->producto_id=$item->id;
     $venta->envio_id=$item->envio_id;
    $venta->save();
    Producto::where('id',$item->id)->delete();
    return view('pruebas');}
```

my route:

```
@foreach ($ticket as $item)<div class="d-flex my-2 justify-content-center">
      <a href="{{ route('insertDelete' , $item) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-label waves-effect right waves-light rounded-pill"><i class="ri-check-double-line label-icon align-middle rounded-pill fs-16 ms-2"></i> Finalizar Compra</a>
  </div>@endforeach
```

my web.php

```
 Route::get('pruebas/', [\App\Http\Controllers\VentaController::class, 'insertDelete'] )->name('insertDelete');
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$item->user_id` actually holds a value other than null?

Comment: yes, the problem is $item, is like not send in route, but i can see all atributes in the principal page, the route is get, post or put? thank u my friend

Comment: Check property fill in model. They should contain user_id

Answer (score 2):

In your routes you didn't specify parameter for route model binding. You are expecting `$item` and in that case you need something like this:

```
Route::get('pruebas/{$item}', [\App\Http\Controllers\VentaController::class, 'insertDelete'] )->name('insertDelete');
```

Comment: i love u  brother

Comment: Can you mark this as best answer if it's helpful? ;)